# Cannot correctly publish a Wcf service on localhost

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, wcf, iis

I am trying to publish a Wcf Service locally (Visual Studio 2013), i have published it on an address in localhost but when i try to connect to it with an other project the "Add Service Reference" window says to me "An error (Details) occurred while attempting to find services at 'http://localhost:53700/AzureWebServiceTest'.".

The only way to use correctly my Wcf Service is add it to the Solution, but i don't think it is the right way.

If i click "Details" i obtain this message:

```
"There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:53700/AzureWebServiceTest/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Rifiuto persistente del computer di destinazione 127.0.0.1:53700
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:53700/AzureWebServiceTest'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:53700/AzureWebServiceTest that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
Unable to connect to the remote server
Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Rifiuto persistente del computer di destinazione 127.0.0.1:53700
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again."
```

UPDATE:
can anyone says me how to simply locally publish a Wcf Service and use it on an other project with the Service Reference?

Comment: Click "Details" and research the error.

Comment: Now i add it to the Question.

Comment: The error says _"Unable to connect to the remote server"_. Please check that the deployment happened like you expected.

Comment: But the problem is that i have configured the Web Service correctly, i have simply done "Publish".

Comment: Your results beg to differ, the message says there is no server listening at that port. How did you "Publish to IIS Express"?

Comment: I have opened Wcf Service project > right click on the project > Publish > ... > Local IIS > Create New Web Application > Rename > it gives me the target location > Publish

Comment: What makes you think that is for IIS Express? That's just regular IIS. Check that the site exists, that it indeed listens on port 53700 and that you can access it from your browser. If not, you don't have to bother with adding a service reference; fix the site first.

Comment: The section IIS Sites says " You must install IIS to view local IIS sites" but i have already install it.

Comment: Which section? Anyway, look: you messed up the installation of either IIS or your site. The problem is not related to WCF, your problem is getting a published site to run. Please update your question with all relevant information.

Comment: I am only trying to get the most simply way to publish a web service locally, so my question is already right, because my problem is how to know the most simply way to test a Wcf Service on another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open an other instance of Visual Studio and execute the application, then with the principal instance find the service with the metaaddres described in the active host (of the Service instance). Et Voilà.